# VB.net basic error with String <-> Char Conversion

Tags: vb.net, string, variables, char, type-conversion

I was programming a little game to pratice myself and i went on an error I weren't able to fix :S. This is the start of an hanging game. (Dont know if its the correct name in english :) ) I need to take a word from a file, 1 per line, and let the player guess the word with a limited numbers of try.

I think my error is related to string/char comparaison and manipulation or, what i write in the text label. I tryed to find some tutorial or problem already solved on internet but nothing was really the same as this ... :(

I change the type of variable many time, read the debugger line per line but I never finded what was wrong .. :S If you are good with VB, plz help me fix that :O (you can also give your comment/improve)

Thx, TheFlame

Code:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Pendu

Public Structure StructMot
    Public MotSecret() As Char
    Public LettreDecouverte() As Char
End Structure

Dim Mot As StructMot
Dim i As Integer = 0

Private Sub ButtonA_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonA.Click, ButtonB.Click,
    ButtonC.Click, ButtonD.Click, ButtonE.Click, ButtonF.Click, ButtonG.Click, ButtonH.Click, ButtonI.Click, ButtonJ.Click,
    ButtonK.Click, ButtonL.Click, ButtonM.Click, ButtonN.Click, ButtonO.Click, ButtonP.Click, ButtonQ.Click, ButtonR.Click,
    ButtonS.Click, ButtonT.Click, ButtonU.Click, ButtonV.Click, ButtonW.Click, ButtonX.Click, ButtonY.Click, ButtonZ.Click

    i = i + 1
    ActiveControl.Visible = False
    PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(i - 1)
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    For j = 0 To Mot.MotSecret.Length - 1
        If ActiveControl.Text = Mot.MotSecret(j) Then
            Mot.LettreDecouverte(j) = Mot.MotSecret(j)
        End If
    Next j

    Label1.Text = ""
    For j = 0 To Mot.MotSecret.Length - 1
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + " "
        If Mot.LettreDecouverte(j).Equals("") Then
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "_"
        Else
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text + Mot.LettreDecouverte(j)
        End If
    Next j

End Sub

Private Sub JouerToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles JouerToolStripMenuItem.Click
    GenereMot()
End Sub

Private Sub Pendu_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    GenereMot()
End Sub

Function GenereMot()
    Dim NbItems As Integer
    Dim Aleatoire As New Random()
    Dim NbAleatoire As Integer
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("listemot.txt"))
    NbItems = ListBox1.Items.Count
    NbAleatoire = Aleatoire.Next(NbItems)
    Mot.MotSecret = ListBox1.Items(NbAleatoire)

    Return Mot
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: What is the actual error message and line number?

Comment: Why are you comparing words based on Char array instead of a string? The French naming makes understanding your algorithm a little difficult. Ce Pas Grave but mon Fracais Ce Pas Esceptionel. If you could post the complete code on github or gist.github.com I would willing to take a deeper look. Bonne Chance.

Comment: They say the error is on this line : If Mot.LettreDecouverte(j).Equals("") Then

Comment: `MotSecret()` in your structure should probably be a String and not a Char...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `Mot.LettreDecouverte` can be `Nothing` i.e. not initialized as you don't set any value for it.

This can cause error to happen both in `Mot.LettreDecouverte(j) = Mot.MotSecret(j)` line and also in `If Mot.LettreDecouverte(j).Equals("") Then...` line of your code.

change your `ButtonA_Click` event handler code as following:

```
i = i + 1
ActiveControl.Visible = False
PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(i - 1)
Dim j As Integer = 0

If Mot.LettreDecouverte Is Nothing OrElse Mot.LettreDecouverte.Length < Mot.MotSecret.Length Then
        Mot.LettreDecouverte = Space(Mot.MotSecret.Length) '* initiate it by enough number of space chars
End If

For j = 0 To Mot.MotSecret.Length - 1
    If ActiveControl.Text = Mot.MotSecret(j) Then
        Mot.LettreDecouverte(j) = Mot.MotSecret(j)
    End If
Next j

Label1.Text = ""
For j = 0 To Mot.MotSecret.Length - 1
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + " "
    If Mot.LettreDecouverte(j).Equals(" "c) Then '*Note: i use space char, not empty string
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "_"
    Else
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + Mot.LettreDecouverte(j)
    End If
Next j
```

**Note that** the value of `Mot.LettreDecouverte(j)` is always a **char** and a char can not be an empty string as you typed in `Mot.LettreDeciouverte(j).Equals("")`. i initiate the LettreDeciouverte with an array of space chars such that we can check its elements comparing against `" "c` char.